# Búsqueda de varios datos con el IN desde C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta  en un procedimiento almacenado **SQL SERVER**

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_BuscarCanasta]
@Condicion nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT  COUNT(TxInvPTCanasta) AS Cantidad,TxInvPTCanasta, T2.ItemName,TxInvPTProducto,T3.DescripcionProducto ,T1.TxInvPTCantidad, 
TxInvPTLote,SUM(TxInvPTPeso) , '1' as #Canasta
FROM  [dbo].[tblinv_txinventarioPT] T1 
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Sap_productos] T2 ON T2.ItemCode = TxInvPTProducto
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblestadoproducto] T3  ON T3.IdEstadoProducto = T1.TxInvPTEstadoProducto
WHERE T1.TxInvPTCanasta IN ('%'+@Condicion+'%') and  (YEAR(T1.TxInvPTFecha) = 2020)
GROUP BY TxInvPTCanasta, T2.ItemName,TxInvPTProducto,T3.DescripcionProducto ,T1.TxInvPTCantidad,TxInvPTLote
```

Como ven el parámetro en el IN quiere decir que busque varios datos, que sin el parámetro seria algo como esto

```
WHERE TxInvPTCanasta IN ('00000181790000000155','00000181790000000172')
```

Desde C# llamo el procedimiento de esta forma

```
public DataTable BuscarCanastas(string Condicion)
    {
        using (var connection = AbrirConexion())
        {
            //  connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SP_BuscarCanasta";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condicion", Condicion);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Creo el método en el formulario para pintar la búsqueda

```
   private void BuscarCanastas(string Condicion)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = objprod.BuscarCanastas(Condicion);
        }
```

Y mando como parámetro lo que este en el TextBox cuando le den click al boton buscar

```
  private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ( txtBuscarCanasta.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("llenar este campo");
            }
            else
            {
                BuscarCanastas(txtBuscarCanasta.Text);
                txtBuscarCanasta.Clear();
            }

        }
```

Pero no encuentro como mandarle varios valores, o sea buscar varias canastas solo recibe una canasta y la busca bien, pero como puedo desde c# mandarle varios valores desde el TextBox creo que el procedimiento esta bien ¿pero desde c# como los mando? seria como poner esto en el TextBox 00000181790000000155,00000181790000000172 pero solo trae uno no los dos

Comment: Podrías empezar por reemplazar el `TextBox` por un select multiple o un `Checklist`; de esta manera recibes lo que va clickeando el usuario en el listado de opciones y lo podrías recibir como un arreglo de valores

Comment: El problema es la forma como sql server maneja los parámetros para evitar la inyección SQL. El parámetro `@Condicion` siempre será tratado como un único texto y no como una lista de valores. ¿Que versión de SQL Server estás utilizando?

Comment: La versión es 18 5.1

Comment: Hola @EstebanGiraldo, eso se parece más a la version del SQL Server Management Studio. Por favor abre un nuevo Query y ejecuta esta instrucción para confirmar `SELECT @@VERSION`. Incluye @PabloGutiérrez en tu respuesta para que la plataforma me de un aviso.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo, Con SQL Server 2019, puedes utilizar la función `STRING_SPLIT` que menciono en mi respuesta

Comment: Si señor solo tuve que utilizar,  ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111689/discussion-between-pablo-gutierrez-and-esteban-giraldo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir de SQL Server 2016 está disponible la función [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que se adapta muy bien a lo que quieres lograr.

Si estás utilizando SQL Server 2016 o superior y tu base de datos tiene un nivel de compatibilidad de 130 en adelante, solo tienes que cambiar la clausula where de tu Stored Procedure de la siguiente manera:

```
...
WHERE T1.TxInvPTCanasta IN ( SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(@Condicion, ',') ) and...
```

asegurate de enviar la cadena separada por coma y sin comillas en cada valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condicion", "00000181790000000155,00000181790000000172");
```

Se puede utilizar cualquier separador distinto de coma siempre que lo especifiques en el segundo parámetro de la función.

Answer (score 2):

Sql server evalúa el parámetro como un elemento individual y no como una lista de valores, por tanto no puede procesarlos como tal.

Una solución es utilizar un código para separar por caracteres el parámetro que recibamos en el procedure.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_BuscarCanasta]
@Condicion nvarchar(4000)
AS
DECLARE @SplitSep VARCHAR(1)=',';
DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
( 
  numParameter Int Identity(1,1)
, value varchar(100)
)


SELECT @Xml = 
CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
  REPLACE(@Condicion , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') +  '</s></r>');

INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) 
        AS Value
       FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);



SELECT COUNT(TxInvPTCanasta) AS Cantidad
     , TxInvPTCanasta
     , T2.ItemName
     , TxInvPTProducto
     , T3.DescripcionProducto
     , T1.TxInvPTCantidad
     , TxInvPTLote
     , SUM(TxInvPTPeso)
     , '1' as #Canasta
       FROM dbo.tblinv_txinventarioPT AS T1
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Sap_productos AS T2 ON T2.ItemCode = TxInvPTProducto
                 INNER JOIN dbo.tblestadoproducto AS T3 ON T3.IdEstadoProducto = T1.TxInvPTEstadoProducto
                 INNER JOIN @TablaParametros T4 ON T1.TxInvPTCanasta = t4.value
       WHERE  YEAR(T1.TxInvPTFecha) = 2020
       GROUP BY TxInvPTCanasta
              , T2.ItemName
              , TxInvPTProducto
              , T3.DescripcionProducto
              , T1.TxInvPTCantidad
              , TxInvPTLote;
```

Con el código separado en filas de una variable tipo tabla, se puede realizar una inner join contra la misma, de manera que solo nos devuelve los registros coincidentes.

En función del motor sql server que dispongas además del nivel de compatibilidad, puedes utilizar diferentes maneras.

La query que te he puesto, se basa en xml y sirve para al menos 2008 y superiores, pero esta realizada al vuelo, sin tener un ejemplo de tus datos, y de los requisitos explícitos.

Además existen múltiples formas de realizar esto. Sobre todo si dispones de un SQL Server 2012 o superior.

[Pasar lista de valores a un procedure](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/pasar-lista-de-valores-a-un-procedure/)

Ya que no hay un ejemplo de los datos, te expongo la solución con una tabla un poco más simple.

```
CREATE TABLE tblinv_txinventarioPT
             (
             ID             INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
           , TxInvPTCanasta NVARCHAR(20)
           , TxInvPTFecha   DATE
           , TxInvPTPeso    Float
             );
GO
INSERT INTO tblinv_txinventarioPT (TxInvPTCanasta, TxInvPTFecha, TxInvPTPeso)
VALUES
('00000181790000000155','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000172','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000133','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000122','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000155','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000172','20200101',1.0),
('00000181790000000133','20200101',1.0);
GO
```

Ahora el procedure:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_BuscarCanasta]
@Condicion nvarchar(4000)
AS
DECLARE @SplitSep VARCHAR(1)=',';
DECLARE @Xml XML;
DECLARE @TablaParametros Table 
( 
  numParameter Int Identity(1,1)
, value varchar(100)
)


SELECT @Xml = 
CONVERT(XML, '<r><s>' + 
  REPLACE(@Condicion , @SplitSep, '</s><s>') +  '</s></r>');

INSERT INTO @TablaParametros
       SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM((T.c.value('.', 'varchar(max)')))) 
        AS Value
       FROM @Xml.nodes('/r/s') T(c);



SELECT COUNT(TxInvPTCanasta) AS Cantidad
     , TxInvPTCanasta
     , SUM(TxInvPTPeso)
       FROM dbo.tblinv_txinventarioPT AS T1
                 INNER JOIN @TablaParametros T4 ON T1.TxInvPTCanasta = t4.value
       WHERE  YEAR(T1.TxInvPTFecha) = 2020
       GROUP BY TxInvPTCanasta

       GO
```

La ejecución, pasando como parámetro "00000181790000000155,00000181790000000172"

[image: Solución]

Comment: Funciona al buscar por un registro, al poner dos registros separados por coma trae otros datos diferentes a los enviados.

Comment: Porque el parámetro de entrada estaba como en tu ejemplo NVARCHAR(30), y si le pasas dos strings de 20 caracteres, y en tu ejemplo utilizabas un patrón para caracteres like % trae cualquier coincidencia. De manera que el primer string de 20 era el que querias, pero del segundo solo tenías 9 caracteres, y por 000001817 seguro que tienes muchos registros. He modificado la respuesta con un ejemplo y con la búsqueda por exactitud del TxInvPTCanasta.

Comment: Si señor, tienes la razón gracias